How do I get rid of this annoying Windows login popup on startup?

The above image reads:

"You have to login into your MS account again if you want to send requests designated towards parents for example if you want more screen time or need permissions for certain apps or webs."

Once I logged into my MS account on my Windows machine, an annoying popup always shows up whenever I open my computer.
The prompt says that I should login into my MS account to not miss any "things" about allowing sites etc. (my machine is under parental control) it prompts me to login even though I'm already logged in, and when I do so it pops up again after "opening" the computer again.
Its been months since I haven't tried getting rid of this popup.

Parental Control requires a Microsoft Account on Windows 8+
